how to prove subset sums are distinct
Here we only take finite sets in account. For example for one set $K=\{6,9, 11,12, 13\}$, we can prove using  exhaustion by one program.
If we take induction on the size $n$ of the subset, then the base case $n=0$ is trivial (also for $n=1$). Let $S_i$ be the set of size-$i$ subset sums. We can prove $S_i,0\le i\le |K|$ are disjoint mutually by inspecting the minimum and maximum sum in $S_i$. But I can't know how to use inductive hypothesis (Maybe that is impossible and the method is a bit inappropriate) to prove sums aren't duplicate in each $S_i$.
When inspecting inside each $S_i,i\ge 2$, I splitted the sums into different small ranges. For example, for $S_2$ we have $6+9<6+13<9+11<9+13<11+12<11+13<12+13$ by categorising based on the minimal element in the 2 numbers. But that is still a bit like  exhaustion although avoiding some unnecessary sum calculation.
Then is there one more elegant way like induction to prove subset sums are distinct?

If the set is very structured, e.g., ${1,2,4,8,16,\dotsc}$, then, yes, there are nice ways. If the set is not so structured, then I'd expect it to be much harder.

There is a lot of research on sets with distinct subsums, and several related questions here (and probably several on MathOverflow). See, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070764/set-with-distinct-subset-sums and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879865/what-do-you-call-a-set-whose-subsets-all-have-unique-sums and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897866/the-sums-of-the-subsets-are-distinct and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629986/largest-set-whose-subsets-have-distinct-sums for starters.

@GerryMyerson Thanks. My textbook mcs.pdf says your offered set which corresponds to binary digits. I have read the 3 links (the 3rd is given one overlook since that seems to be not related with my question).
